# Error found when loading /etc/profile [mariadb,mysql]

Tags: permissions, mysql, .profile, mariadb, etc

Booting to Ubuntu 19.04 I get black screen (frozen and not able to press the OK button) with this error message popup:

> Error found when loading /etc/profile
>
> find:'/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/auth_pam_tool_dir': Permission denied
>
> As a result the session will not be configured correctly. You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.

- the last thing done where installing MariaDB by adding the repo to list and installing via `apt`. Adding some paths like, java_home, catalina, maven,... To path.
- Also I did create `.bash_profile` to add those variables (according to React-Native instructions).
- did the `sudo apt update & sudo apt upgrade` I saw something related to mysql was in the list of updating packages, logged out and on logging back in facing the above error.

How should I enter the system to change permissions? And what should be the permission for the directory?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem on three computers, but interestingly it was when I updated them.

In Software sources, I put the one from MariaDB:
http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu

The solution I can offer you is the following:
Console:

```
sudo chmod -R 644 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/auth_pam_tool_dir/
```

Stays with user `mysql.root`.
I believe that if MariaDB repositories are not used and those of Ubuntu are used, the error will not occur.

Comment: Thanks, I already have done the same, gave permission of everything to everyone, but on updating the package, all permissions returned to its default. I really got confused with the permissions in this case